# Problem with show/hide function somehow refreshes the page

Tags: jquery

I can successfully show the div that I want to show and hide, but disappears as soon as it shows. It seems like the page refreshes for some reason.

Here is the sample code. The div should not disappear when I click it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#c_button").click(function() {
    $("#c_show").show();
  });
  $("#b_button").click(function() {
    $("#b_show").show();
  });
  $("#s_button").click(function() {
    $("#s_show").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <button class="btn btn-danger form-control" id="c_button">Customer</button>
      <button class="btn btn-info form-control" id="b_button">Branch</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="s_button">Supplier</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- 
    these are the divs I want to show
    Note: the divs should be hidden by default
  -->
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="c_show" style="display:none;">
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <label>Customer: </label>
      <input type="text" name="samp1" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="b_show" style="display:none;">
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <label>Branch: </label>
      <input type="text" name="samp2" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="c_show" style="display:none;">
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <label>Supplier: </label>
      <input type="text" name="samp3" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the HTML you've shown within a `form` element? Also note that there is no `#s_show` element in the example. I presume the last duplicated `#c_show` should have that id, but there's a typo.

Comment: Dont worry about it I just forgot to write it. @Rory McCrossan and yes it is within a form

Comment: The code is working fine for me, except the typo mentioned above.

Comment: Note: It is inside a form @natsuozawa

Comment: Then that is the problem. I added a solution for you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments under the question

> The HTML is within a form

Then this is the problem. By default all `button` elements are of `type="submit"`, hence when they are clicked they will submit the parent `form` element. To stop this, change then to `type="button"`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger form-control" id="c_button">Customer</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info form-control" id="b_button">Branch</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="s_button">Supplier</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all try to call your jquery at the end of your code

```
// call here 
</body>
```

Comment: This does not address the issue in any way.